# Unable to add columns in a particular table

Tags: oracle-12c

I am trying to add 4 columns on a table using the below command

```
alter table table_name
add
(column_1 number(4),
 column_2 varchar2(10),
 column_4 number(4),
 column_5 varchar2(10));
```

The table contains 18,057,945 records and has a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger. The alter command gets stuck and returns after 2 hours with the below error.

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-04030: out of process memory when trying to allocate 216 bytes (kxsbbinfo,adl context curMsgBuf)
```

Note that I ran the same alter statement on 3 other tables which are basically snapshots of the same table with similar index,trigger etc. and it took around 0.06, 0.03,0.05 seconds to run the alter command.

I have checked other questions like [this..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54815549/oracle-12c-adding-column-to-table-without-default-value-taking-really-long) but it provides no insight on this particular challenge I am facing, and I have not added any not-null/default value in my alter statement. There are no locks on the table and also there is no active cursor as well on the given table...

Please advise. I have a test environment and a production environment. The funny thing is that the alter for this particular table is getting stuck and giving the same error in both the environments.

Please advise what I can check/do!! Thanks in advance.

I also analyzed/gather stats for this table in between tries to alter it!!!

```
ANALYZE TABLE table_name ESTIMATE STATISTICS FOR ALL INDEXED COLUMNS SIZE 75 SAMPLE 100 PERCENT;

EXEC dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('xx','table_name' ,cascade=>TRUE);
```

Comment: Can you double check if there are any DDL triggers in your database ?